# How to stream audio from VLC to AirPlay speakers?

Tags: audio, airport, airplay, vlc

My configuration looks like this:

- MacBook with EL Capitan
- AirPort Express 802.11n (2nd Generation)
- speakers connected to AirPort's audio port using mini-jack

On my MacBook I switched audio output to AirPort Express and it's working quite well when playing music from iTunes, Spotify or YouTube in Safari. Sound quality is good, audio is in sync with video on the MacBook's screen.

The problem appears when I am trying to play some movies using VLC app. With this configuration, the sound that comes from my "wireless" speakers is choppy and its quality is very bad. Playing the same video file with Quick Time Player solves the problem - audio is perfect. Not all video files are affected by this issue. Some can be played with VLC without an issue.

When using MacBook's internal speakers all video files can be played without an issue using VLC. Choppy, poor quality audio only occurs when audio output is set to AirPort Express.

I assume that the problem could be connected to audio codec used to create video files I am trying to play. I could just play this files using Quick Time Player and both video (on MacBook's screen) and audio (from speakers connected to AirPort) would be perfect, but I like the VLC and how its support subtitles etc.

What should I do to fix audio issues when playing movies in VLC with AirPlay speakers?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and would be really glad if someone could provide a solution.

Comment: Not sure why, but using third party software - Air Parrot - fixes the issue. Anyway, I don't like it much and I am still waiting for someone that understands where the problem is and can explain it or suggest a solution that doesn't require installing additional (paid) software.

Comment: Make sure your VLC playback volume is not above 100%